# Objects are shaking during rendering in Android GLES 1.0.

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a little bit of trouble with fixing bug in my game engine.

My problem is that I see elements of my hud shaking when I am moving my camera in the scene.
Bug only appears when my camera is moved by finger slide. 
When I change it position in update method everything seems to be fine.

Render method (called from onDrawFrame() in main activity):

```
public void drawScene(GL10 gl)
{
    // Clear scene
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Move left top corner of camera to specified point
    gl.glTranslatef(-camera.getX(), screenManager.getScreenHeight() - camera.getY(), 0f);
    // Render all objects from the scene
    root.renderObjects(gl);
    // Fixed position for HUD elements
    gl.glTranslatef(camera.getX(), -screenManager.getScreenHeight() + camera.getY(), 0.0f);
    // Render hud to the screen
    hud.renderObjects(gl);
    // Get back to camera position
    gl.glTranslatef(-camera.getX(), screenManager.getScreenHeight() - camera.getY(), 0.0f);
    // Reset the matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Moving method (called from onTouchEvent in main activity):

```
public void onPointerMove(TouchPointer pointer, TouchPointer historicalPointer)
{
    Point p = new Point(pointer.getRawTouchPoint());
    p.subtract(historicalPointer.getRawTouchPoint());
    camera.moveBy(p);
}
```

I think this is the code that matters. But I don't see anything that I could change.
If anyone got any idea please share ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would change drawScene to

```
public void drawScene(GL10 gl)
{
    // Clear scene
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Move left top corner of camera to specified point
    gl.glTranslatef(-camera.getX(), screenManager.getScreenHeight() - camera.getY(), 0f);
    // Render all objects from the scene
    root.renderObjects(gl);
    // Fixed position for HUD elements
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // Render hud to the screen
    hud.renderObjects(gl);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

See if it helped. The problem may be in changing camera position during renderObject (for example from external thread), or even float not being enough precise.